# Sum of field matching certain criteria

Tags: mysql

I am trying to sum different fields of rows that match certain criterias. But my query only returns the first row of those criterias and doesn't sum up the fields.

My database:

```
id  | project |           end           | duration|
4   |    a    |   2021-04-16 12:46:38   |  10800  |
3   |    a    |   2021-04-16  8:14:12   |  14400  |
2   |    b    |   2021-04-16  1:54:18   |   8400  |
1   |    b    |   2021-04-16  1:17:46   |   900   |
```

My query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sum(duration) from tasks WHERE project='b' AND DATE(end)=CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY");
```

But that query results:

```
900
```

It should result:

```
9.300
```

What's wrong on my query?

Comment: I see nothing in your sample data that would add up to 9.3. indeed, every value is significantly larger.

Comment: Works for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5m3n9Mat7aQ3h6241r7Xvy/0

Comment: Incidentally, a range comparison would be more efficient

Comment: E.g.: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rwhu262RMghwWZncVDUV5Q/0

Comment: Thanks Strawberry - I changed my query a bit and rebuild it using 'between'. That works perfectly now. Not really sure why, but it works.